# how to handle request header accept application/ld+json in react.js get request

Tags: javascript

how to handle request header accept application/ld+json in react.js get request

> Media type
>   application/id+json
>   Controls Accept header.

i am getting unauthorized 401 error dont know why can anyone please explain me i am facing this type of error for the first time .

```
function parseJwt(token) {
  if (!token) { return; }
  const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
  const base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
  return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
}

export async function getRequest(url , token){
  let token_data = parseJwt(token) 
  console.log('Token data ', token_data)
  let response = await fetch(API_URL(url), {
    method: "GET", 
    mode: "cors", 
    cache: "no-cache",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Accept": `application/${token_data.id}+json`,
      // 'Content-Type': `application/${token_data.id}+json`,
      // "Authorization": JSON.stringify(token_data)
    },
    redirect: "follow",
    referrer: "no-referrer",  
  })

  return response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Below code

var token = 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX';
const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': token
      },
      body: payLoad,
    })